# How can you put these two datatypes: `RowF Maybe` and `Maybe (RowF Identity)` into the same List?

Tags: haskell, types

I have the following data types:

```
data RowF f = RowF { rsidf      :: f String
                    , rtimef    :: f Double
                   }

type Row    = RowF Identity


realizeRow :: RowF Maybe -> Maybe Row
```

And I would like to have a list of both `Row` and `RowF Maybe`. That is to say I might have:

```
[RowF (Maybe "hello") Nothing, Maybe (RowF "world" 12.3)]
```

Someone suggested I should implement some function:

```
f :: (forall x. f x -> g x) -> RowF f -> RowF g
```

But I am not sure what this is meant to do or how to implement it.

Comment: Why do you want this? Are some of those `Maybe`s supposed to be `Just`s?

Comment: To clarify what @dfeuer is saying... why do you want to have a list containing both `RowF Identify` and `RowF Maybe` values? Show us some example code you would like to write if you could construct such a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple solutions.

You could use `Either` to wrap the two types:

```
ghci> let rm = RowF (Just "hello") Nothing :: RowF Maybe
ghci> let mr = Just (RowF (Identity "world") (Identity 12.3)) :: Maybe Row
ghci> :t [ Left rm, Right mr ]
[ Left rm, Right mr ] :: [ Either (RowF Maybe) (Maybe Row) ]
```

Alternately, you could create some functions to convert back and forth

```
toRow :: Applicative f => RowF f -> f Row
toRow (RowF fs fd) = (\s d -> RowF (Identity s) (Identity d)) <$> fs <*> fd

fromRow :: Functor f => f Row -> RowF f
fromRow fr = RowF (runIdentity . rsidf <$> fr) (runIdentity . rtimef <$> fr)
```

Then just convert to one type to the other as needed.

```
ghci> :t [ rm, fromRow mr ]
[ rm, fromRow mr ] :: [RowF Maybe]
ghci> :t [ toRow rm, mr ]
[ toRow rm, mr ] :: [Maybe Row]
```

Alternately, you could create a wrapper that wraps all `RowF f`, and use that:

```
ghci> :set -XRankNTypes -XConstraintKinds -XExistentialQuantification
ghci> data RowC c = forall f. RowC { runRowC :: c f => RowF f }
ghci> let ri = RowF (Identity "world") (Identity 12.3) :: Row 
ghci> :t [ RowC rm, RowC ri ] :: [ RowC Monad ]
[ RowC rm, RowC ri ] :: [ RowC Monad ] :: [RowC Monad]
```

The drawback of this approach is once you convert a `RowF f` to a `RowC c`, you can't convert back, and you can't do anything
with the value outside of the operations defined by the constraint `c`.

That last suggestion you got, to define

```
convert :: (forall x. f x -> g x) -> RowF f -> RowF g
convert f2g (RowF fs fd) = RowF (f2g fs) (f2g fd)
```

Would allow you to convert from `Row` to `RowF Maybe` easily.

```
ghci> :t convert (Just . runIdentity) ri
convert (Just . runIdentity) ri :: RowF Maybe
```